# pandas read_excel adds fractional seconds that don't appear in original xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an excel spreadsheet into pandas as:

`input_df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_excel(data_filename, engine='openpyxl')`

Here's a screenshot of the beginning of the excel file:

[image]

However, when I exam the dataframe, fractional parts are added to two out of the three time columns.

```
Out[6]: 
         Real Time  Current(nA)  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3    Sensor 4 Time  Sensor 4 Current nA  Unnamed: 6   FS Time  FS Value
0  11:58:03.111700      119.400         NaN         NaN         10:53:39              119.428         NaN  10:43:12     101.0
1  11:58:04.681197      119.439         NaN         NaN  10:53:40.795800              119.474         NaN  10:44:06     103.0
2  11:58:07.246866      119.417         NaN         NaN  10:53:43.214300              119.447         NaN  10:51:36      88.0
3  11:58:09.388763      119.416         NaN         NaN  10:53:45.294400              119.439         NaN  10:53:39      88.0
4  11:58:11.454134      119.411         NaN         NaN  10:53:47.302400              119.451         NaN  11:06:58      83.0
```

These don't appear in the original excel file as evidenced by the screenshot below:

[image]
I have no idea where these fractions come from.  They don't appear in the original file.  Why is this happening, and how can I read in the correct times?

Answer (score 0):

OK.  This was my fault.  It turns out that there is a fractional part to the timestamps.  Google sheets needed to be configured to show that fractional part.  In summary, it appears that there is agreement between the xlsx file and the pandas dataframe.